# AlarmManager is not sending notifications at the correct time

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I'm creating an app. In this app ı need to send notifications. But ı have a problem. When notifications interval is one minute, it's working well. But when ı try to change notifications interval fifteen min or higher, notifications  sendingn early. And doing this only one time. I searched and tried different methods as above this(setwindow, setexact). But ı am still getting this problem.

```
public void sendNotifications(){
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        if ((calendar.getTime().getHours() >= starthour) && (calendar.getTime().getHours() <= stopHour )){
            if((startminute<calendar.getTime().getMinutes()) || (calendar.getTime().getHours() >= starthour) && (stopMinute>calendar.getTime().getMinutes() ||calendar.getTime().getHours() <= stopHour) ){



                Intent intent = new Intent(WaterSettingsActivity.this,NotifyReceiver.class);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(WaterSettingsActivity.this,0,intent,0);

                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                int n = sharedPreferences.getInt("spnNotify",0);

                long notificationsFrequency = Long.parseLong(notifySpinner[n]) *1000*60;



                alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),  notificationsFrequency,  pendingIntent);
                Log.i("w",String.valueOf(calendar.getTimeInMillis()));
                Log.i("w",String.valueOf(notificationsFrequency));
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
if (userModel.isReminderOn) {
                //region Enable Daily Notifications
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

                Logger.e("call_cln_day :: " + userModel.scheduleWeekDay + " call week :: " + userModel.scheduleTime);

                calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, userModel.scheduleWeekDay);
                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, userModel.scheduleTime);
                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, AppConstant.MIN);
                calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                // if notification time is before selected time, send notification the next day
                if (calendar.before(Calendar.getInstance())) {
                    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
                }
                if (manager != null) {
                    manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AppConstant.INTERVAL, pendingIntent);
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                        manager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
                    }
                }
                //To enable Boot Receiver class
                pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
            } else {
                //Disable Daily Notifications
                if (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, alarmIntent, 0) != null && manager != null) {
                    manager.cancel(pendingIntent);
                }
                pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
            }
```